# Android Studio: Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have installed below Android version and used some of the latest SDK versions as per the below image and also used the latest gradle version same as shown in the below image and I have also tried downgrading and upgrading multiple grade versions but still getting the below error can anyone help me on that? or have you faced this type of specific error?

```
Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9514443, built on January 21, 2023
Runtime version: 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 16
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin (3.7.4)
    Dart (221.6096)
    com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.8)
    io.flutter (72.1.2)
```

[image]

[image]

**ERROR FACING:**

```
* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
   > Could not create plugin of type 'VersionCheckPlugin'.
      > com/google/common/base/Splitter
* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
   > Could not create plugin of type 'VersionCheckPlugin'.
      > Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.VersionCheckPlugin

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.exceptionOccurred(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:223)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:205)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:147)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.access$200(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$1$1.lambda$add$1(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:120)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyPlugins$0(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:143)
    

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 421ms
```